# Disable text selection on right click

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, nwjs

I'm writing a desktop app using nwjs, and I want to use the right mouse button for some UI functions. This is working pretty ok right now; I am able to disable the context menu when the right click was for a UI function.

However, I am having an awful time figuring out how to not *only* stop right click events from opening a context menu, but also to stop them from selecting the text under the cursor.

Here is an example of what is happening (that I do not want to happen) - I am left-click dragging a handle to resize a UI view, and then while the left mouse is held down I am right clicking to cancel the resize. When the right click ends over any text, the text is selected. (Normally, a context menu would also appear.)

[image: GIF of unwanted behavior]

When handling the right mouse down event and context menu event, I am calling `event.preventDefault()` and returning `false`.

What the actual event handler code looks like (appearing in the same order as the events are spawned and handled)...

```
this.windowMouseDownListener = event => {
    if(this.draggingResize &&
        event.button === 2 && !event.ctrlKey
    ){
        for(let view of this.area.views){
            view.size = view.sizeBeforeDrag;
        }
        this.area.updateElementSizes();
        this.draggingResize = false;
        this.recentDraggingResize = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
};
this.windowContextMenuListener = event => {
    if(this.recentDraggingResize){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
this.windowMouseUpListener = event => {
    this.sizeBeforeDrag = this.size;
    if(this.size <= 0.0001){
        this.area.removeView(this);
    }
    if(this.draggingResize || this.recentDraggingResize){
        this.recentDraggingResize = false;
        this.draggingResize = false;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
};
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Change css `user-select` property and make it `user-select: none;` Just as you disabled the context menu in this event: recentDraggingResize.